# Notepad++ NppFTP SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, notepad++, sftp, ssh-tunnel

I am currently stuck on whether it is possible to connect via SSH Tunnel on Notepad++ Extension NppFTP?

I can connect via SFTP to the server directly however about to loose that connectivity and thus looking into tunneling similar to doing so on WinSCP and PuTTY.

Comment: Have you done all the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-ftp-with-notepad/)?

Comment: Yes have done the above I can connect this way however will need to connect via tunnel/via jumpbox and cannot find details on how to do so via notepad++

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it does clearly state SFTP in the question? however yes it is SFTP I will be connecting via using the NppFTP extension on Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that NppFTP supports tunneling natively.

But you can use a tunnel created in PuTTY or WinSCP in NppFTP.

For example, if you setup tunnel in PuTTY, you can connect to the forwarded port in NppFTP, as long as you keep the PuTTY session open.

Similarly with WinSCP tunnel. In WinSCP, you should set fixed ["Local tunnel port"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel#tunnel_options), instead of default "autoselect".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also mount the remote filesystem using `sshfs` like so:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/d
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@host.com:/media/d /mnt/d
```

This way you can edit the "remote" files mounted locally with NPP